# Storing Lists Inside An Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object, reference

Is it possible to store a Class that contains a List inside an array?

I am having some trouble with this concept.

Here's my code:

My Class Called "arrayItems":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EngineTest
{
    [Serializable] //List olarak save etmemiz için bu gerekli.
    public class arrayItems
    {
        public List<items> items = new List<items>();
    }
}
```

Here's the definition of my Array called "tileItems":

```
 public static arrayItems[, ,] tileItems;
```

Here's how I create my Array:

```
    Program.tileItems = new arrayItems[Program.newMapWidth, Program.newMapHeight, Program.newMapLayers];
```

The problem I am facing is that the content of my Array is null.
And I am getting this error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

When I try to populate the List inside the array by Add() command I get the same error.

Can you direct me to the right direction please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You instantiate the array `titleItems`, so the space for `arrayItems` references has been allocated but, you haven't set the references to valid instances of the `arrayItems` classes.

Comment: A quick workaround would be to change `public class arrayItems` to `public struct arrayItems`, then `arrayItems` would then be a value type, not a reference type. However this could have other undesired side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already initializing the list within the class definition you do not need to re-initialize the list property of `arrayItems` within the loop.

You have an array that has a bunch of pointers that point to nothing. So you actually need to instiante a new `arrayItems` in each array element first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newMapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newMapHeight; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < newMapLayers; k++)
        {
            arrayItems[i,j,k]= new arrayitem();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialise each list within the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newMapWidth; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newMapHeight; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < newMapLayers; k++)
        {
            arrayItems[i,j,k] = new arrayItems();
        }
    }
}
```

first.

Comment: Shouldn't that be arrayitems[i,j,k] = new arrayItems()?

Comment: Do you mean this: 

"Program.tileItems[x, y, z].items = new List<items>();"

Comment: I think I'd favour `x`, `y` and `z` for iterators but yes.

Comment: @Theoden No, you need to create instances of the `arrayItems` itself first, they aren't magically created.  In addition, you create a new instance of the list when each `arrayItems` object is created with the line `public List<items> items = new List<items>();`.  Since you have the `new` keyword there you know that a *new* list is being created.

Comment: @Jodrell i, j, and k are standard variable names for loop variables when you go 3 deep.

Comment: @Servy, but x, y, and z are a common convention for describing Width, Height and Depth respectively. Since this context iterates over those dimensions it seemed appropriate and simple.

Comment: @Jodrell I'm not saying I'd object if you used x, y, and z in your own answer, but i, j, and k are the convention, so using them is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating and array of `arrayItems`, which is a reference type, because you defined it as a class. So when you initialize your array, all elements will be assigned `null` by default. That's why you get the error. You have to initialize each element of your array.